# Inheritance of structs without member functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

This question is likely a "what does the C++ standard say" thing, but my Google searching hasn't given me the answer I'm looking for.

I know that when you have classes, and you have one class inherit from another class, you get into the world of virtual function tables, since the code needs to figure out which class contains the function you're trying to call.

But what about inheritance between structs that only contain data? For example, if you have a widget struct, and then you want a specialized version of that struct that has a few extra variables, but you still want to be able to pass its original data to functions that handle widgets, it would be simpler to inherit from the original widget struct than to make your code handle two types of widget structs. Is there any overhead when there is only data involved in the inheritance? Is the specialized widget still a simple struct (in terms of memory layout) with both data combined, or is the original widget data stored separate from the new data?

Ultimately, I'd like to keep my data simple and contiguous, as a basic struct would be, and I don't know if inheriting data would break that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C++ memory model an object is always laid out in contiguous memory. You need to use members pointing to data outside this object if you want to have non-contiguous memory. That is, if you inherit any class whether it is a struct or has virtual function, the actual object is always contiguous. There are few other implications about types which may be of interested: if a class is a standard layout type you can e.g. `memcpy()` the object. I'm not sure what C++2011 says about inheritance and standard layout type but I'm pretty sure that C++2003 didn't allow inheritance and C++2011 allows it.

Answer (score 1):

> know that when you have classes, and you have one class inherit from another class, you get into the world of virtual function tables

only if you have virtual functions...

so to answer your question: if you have a plain `struct` without member functions, then the compiler won't generate a virtual function table.

and BTW you shouldn't be worrying about it, that table is per class, and you only need a simple extra pointer per instance (if you use simple inheritance).

Comment: Very true. I mentioned it as an example of stuff going on behind the scenes when you use inheritance. I don't know if there is some similar stuff going on behind the scenes for the data members.

Comment: @Nairou: No, there isn't, because data members are not polymorphic.